# how to make aws cognito as authentication in asp.net rest api

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito

how to make aws cognito as authentication in asp.net rest api, That is asp.net rest api will be hosted in IIS and its authentication should be from aws cognito, please give if this is possible?

Comment: Amazon Cognito does not have it's own authentication, it simply leverages other authentication systems. Can you clarify exactly what it is you want to be able to do in your application?

Comment: we are planning to have AWS as authetication backend for Google and facebook accounts. And then part of the backend will be in IIS and My Sql, Part of the backend will be amazon dynamo DB, This is to ease the load on the IIS server.